# Output results of `mix hex.docs offline` as EPUB instead of HTML

Tags: elixir, hex-pm

I keep offline copies of the documentation for Hex packages via `mix hex.docs offline PACKAGE_NAME`. This creates an HTML directory in `~/.hex/docs/hexpm/PACKAGE_NAME/`.

I would like to do the same thing, but with the output as EPUB instead of HTML, and **ideally, in one step**.

How can I download offline EPUBs for documentation of packages hosted on Hex.pm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of December 2019, it is [currently not possible to do this in one step without using `ex_doc` directly](https://github.com/hexpm/hex/issues/731), but it appears that there are [plans to support EPUB generation by default in a future release](https://github.com/hexpm/hex/issues/732).